# Angular2 change detection is missing my assigned value... (async)

Tags: angular

So I have this that's driving me nutz!
I have a custom component,

```
<InputEdit [style]="stylesDesc" [showIcon]="true" [editable]="true" [value]="nameEmail"></InputEdit>
```

and I am passing to it a value into nameEmail....
BUT, I am passing the value LATER after the InputEdit has already been instantiated. I can see that InputEdit  is in fact receiving the value I am passing but the UI is not reflecting the value I am passing async (after it comes back from the server).

I tried disabling all changeDetection (or set to ChangeDetectionStrategy.CheckAlways) on that component and its parent.

I even tried extreme updating the zone.js via crazy:

```
     setTimeout(()=> {
            self.ref.detectChanges();
            self.appRef.tick();
            self.zone.run(() => {
                console.log('enabled time travel');
            });
        }, 3000);
```

On both InputEdit and its parent component, and no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to update the UI... UNLESS I put a breakpoint at which point the data from server is available and all is well... very odd!

any idea?

here is the InputEdit component, nothing special about it:
https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/blob/master/src/comps/inputedit/InputEdit.ts

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: Why do you have `value="{{_value}}"` and `[(ngModel)]="_value"`?  The ngModel binding will bind to the `value` property of the `input`.  Try removing `value="{{_value}}"` and see if that helps.

Comment: ok will give it shot, BUT, this is an editable label, when you click it, it will become an Input this the ngModel for the input...

Comment: so ya no luck,,, if you look at the code you will see that ngModel is for the input (which works fine by the way) it's the label that's not getting updates

Comment: How are you getting the data?  Are you using Angular's `http` or something else?  Can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

and also forced CD manually via:

```
constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

updateUi() {
    try {
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

which still I am not sure why I have to, as the component I am updating the value to is a child component and specified in my template, so change detection should kick in even without the ref.detectChanges()... but this does seem to solve the problem. I did have to wrap it in a catch to avoid a stack pending call on a destroyed reference while navigation away...

regards

Sean